# Illuminate\Database\QueryException | SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name

Tags: laravel, migration

When I command in my terminal **php artisan migrate** for create new migration table then throw this error:

```
Illuminate\Database\QueryException 

SQLSTATE[42S21]: Column already exists: 1060 Duplicate column name 
'stripe_id' (SQL: alter table `users` add `stripe_id` varchar(255) null, add 
`card_brand` varchar(255) null, add `card_last_four` varchar(4) null, add 
`trial_ends_at` timestamp null)
```

My migration table code:

```
    public function up()
     {
       Schema::create('my_logos', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('logo_img');
        $table->timestamps();
      });
    }
     }
```

[error image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TMZQq.png)

Comment: Either You didn't run your SQL via XAMPP,WAMP or You put a wrong credentials in your .env file.

Answer (score 0):

Make migration like : php artisan make:migration updatePostTable

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::table('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->dropColumn(['body', 'title']);
        });
    }
```